# SQL make rows into columns, PIVOT maybe

Tags: sql-server

I have an MS SQL Server with a database for an E-commerce storefront.

This is some of the tables I have:

```
Products:  
Id | Name | Price

ProductAttributeTypes: -Color, Size, Format  
Id | Name

ProductAttributes: --Red, Green, 12x20 cm, Mirrored  
Id | ProductAttributeTypeId | Name

Orders:  
Id | DateCreated

OrderItems:  
Id | OrderId | ProductId

OrderItemsToProductAttributes: --Relates an OrderItem to its product and selected attributes  
OrderItemId | ProductAttributeId | ProductAttributeTypeId | ProductId
```

I want to select from the OrderItems table, to see which items have been purchased.

To see what kind of variants (ProductAtriibutes) was selected, I want those as "dynamic" columns in the resultset.

So the resultset should look like this:

```
OrderItemId | ProductId | ProductName | Color | Size | Format  
       1234         123   Mount. Bike   Red     2x20   Mirror
```

I don't know if PIVOT is the thing to use? I'm not using any aggregate functions, so I guess not...

Is there any SQL Ninjas that can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sql2005 or 2008 you can use the pivot command.  See [here.](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/28165)

In the example below the OrderAttributes set will look like:

```
 OrderItemId AttName AttValue
       -----  ------  -----
        100 Color   Red
        100 Size    Small
        101 Color   Blue
        101 Size    Small
        102 Color   Red
        102 Size    Small
        103 Color   Blue
        103 Size    Large
```

The final results after the PIVOT will be:

```
OrderItemId Size  Color
  -----    ------  -----
    100 Small   Red
    101 Small   Blue
    102 Small   Red
    103 Large   Blue

WITH OrderAttributes(OrderItemId, AttName, AttValue)
   AS (
      SELECT 
         OrderItemId, 
         pat.Name AS AttName,
         pa.Name AS AttValue
      FROM OrderItemsToProductAttributes x
      INNER JOIN ProductAttributes pa 
      ON x.ProductAttributeId = pa.id
      INNER JOIN ProductAttributeTypes pat
      ON pa.ProductAttributeTypeId =  pat.Id
   )

SELECT AttrPivot.OrderItemId,
[Size] AS [Size],
[Color] AS Color
FROM OrderAttributes
PIVOT ( 
      MAX([AttValue])
      FOR [AttName] IN ([Color],[Size])
   ) AS AttrPivot
ORDER BY AttrPivot.OrderItemId
```

There is a way to dynamically build the columns (i.e. the Color and Size columns), as can be seen [here.](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)   Make sure your database compatibility level on your database is set to something greater than 2000 or you will get strange errors.

Comment: How? When I'm not using any aggregate functions? I don't want to sum up Ids or anything like that.

Comment: I think this one is very close now - but the value of both Color and Size columns are null. Maybe just a small detail missing?

Comment: One thing might cause a diff, you had ProductAttributeTypeId in the table OrderItemsToProductAttributes, I didn't put this in my sample b/c this should be referenced thru the joins (third normal form and all).  If you are saying that they could have nulls, then something should be changed to something like:
SELECT AttrPivot.OrderItemId,
isnull([Size],'NA') AS [Size],
isnull([Color],'NA') AS Color
FROM OrderAttributes

Comment: It doesn't have null values.

I don't know why it returns null, though.

If I run the query inside the WITH statement, I get all the correct data returned - no nulls. But running the entire query, gives me null values for the Size and Color columns.

Comment: I got it working. The reason was that the name of each attribute is not stored as Color, Size and so. It is stored as an XML string with a number of culture specific values to accommodate internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've created physical tables for read purposes only. The structure you have above is GREAT for storage, but terrible for reporting.

So you could do the following:
Write a script (that is scheduled nightly) or a trigger (on data change) that does the following tasks:

First, you would dynamically go through each Product and build a static table "Product_[ProductName]"

Then go through each ProductAttributeTypes for each product and create/update/delete a physical column on the corresponding Product table.

Then, fill that table with the proper values based on OrderItemsToProductAttributes and ProductAttributes

This is just a rough idea. Make sure you are storing OrderID in the "Static"/"Flattened" tables. And make sure you do everything else you need to do. But after that, you should be able to start pulling from those flattened tables to get the data you need.

Comment: I get your point. I agree that database design for storage vs. reporting has its conflicts and limitations.

But I don't think this query is heavy enough to make use of aggregated tables, as it gives me other problems like redundancy, delays in updates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot is your best bet, but what I did for reporting purposes, and to make it work well with SSIS is to create a view, which then has this query:

```
SELECT     [InputSetID], [InputSetName], CAST([470] AS int) AS [Created By], CAST([480] AS datetime) AS [Created], CAST([479] AS int) AS [Updated By], CAST([460] AS datetime) 
                      AS [Updated]
FROM         (SELECT     st.InputSetID, st.InputSetName, avt.InputSetID AS avtID, avt.AttributeID, avt.Value
                       FROM          app.InputSetAttributeValue avt JOIN
                                              app.InputSets st ON avt.InputSetID = st.InputSetID) AS p PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR AttributeID IN ([470], [480], [479], [460])) AS pvt
```

Then I can just interact with the view, but, I have a trigger on the table that any new dynamic attributes must be added to, which recreates this view, so I can assume the view is always correct.